# Existence of a vector with desired distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Suppose that there exists a random vector $\eta\equiv (\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3)$ **continuously** distributed on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and with **full support**. Can we always find a vector $\epsilon\equiv (\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3)$ **continuously** distributed on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and with **full support**
such that
$$
\eta_1\equiv \epsilon_1-\epsilon_3\\
\eta_2\equiv \epsilon_1-\epsilon_2\\
\eta_3\equiv \epsilon_2-\epsilon_3\\
$$

If yes, how can we show it? If not, can you provide a counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix} \epsilon = \eta$, but this matrix is not invertible, so the vectors of the form $(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_3, \epsilon_1-\epsilon_2, \epsilon_2 - \epsilon_3)$ cannot span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Consider $$(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_3) - (\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2) - (\epsilon_2-\epsilon_3)$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm not understanding it, sorry. Could you help more? Is it a proof for "yes", or a counterexample for "no"?

Comment: @user3285148  It is a hint to help you find the answer.  What happens when you simplify my expression? Now suppose $\eta_1 -\eta_2-\eta_3 \not = 0$ such as $\eta_1=10, \eta_2=2,\eta_3=3$.  Can you see why there is no possible $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3$ satisfying your requirements?